# Синонимизировать метки [объект] и [объекты]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте есть метка [объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) без описания, 7 вопросов. Нужно её синонимизировать с меткой [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 8 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 7 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 7 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'объект': [объект] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 1112
tag remapping of [объекты] and [объект] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym объект -> объекты was approved!
```